# How to redirect via htaccess to a new URL structure

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I've got a problem with redirecting and rewriting rules via htaccess.

I need to change this URL:

```
www.mydomain.com/category/product-a/
```

to

```
www.mydomain.com/products/category/product-a/
```

I am using htaccess with a set of rules. I can make a new URL working, but I need to redirect the old structure to the new one. I do not want to have the same content on two different URLs.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: So, `category` and `product-a` could be "anything" or limited to a specific subset or set of characters? It's important to be as restrictive as possible to avoid conflicts with other directives. The solution may also be dependent on other directives in your `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file, using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/[\w-]+/)$ /products/$1 [R,L]
```

This redirects `/<category>/<product>/` to `/products/<category>/<product>/` where `<category>` and `<product>` can consist of the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore) or `-` (hyphen).

This is also a temporary (302) redirect, change the `R` to `R=301` only once you have confirmed that it works as intended.

Comment: If this helped to answer your question, then please mark it as "accepted" (tick/checkmark on the left below the voting arrows) to remove it from the unanswered question queue and to help other readers. Once you have 15+ rep then you can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)